# Angular Dynamic Colors - SASS

Tags: css, angular, dynamic, sass, styling

**Edit: I don't want to use the angular theming where we can use the predefined palettes. I want to use the custom colors for both the dark and light classes.**

Can we have a styles.sass( which is the main sass) file as follows:

```
.light {
    $background:#ffffff;
    $text-foreground: #000000;
    $text-foreground-onhover: #ffffff;
    $text-background-onhover: #000000;
}

.dark{
    $background:#000000;
    $text-foreground: #ffffff;
    $text-foreground-onhover: #000000;
    $text-background-onhover: #ffffff;
}
```

and in the individual component's sass file.. (let's say dummycomp.sass)
(It throws an error even if i Import the main.sass in the dummycomp.sass as the $text-foreground is not directly accessible :( )

```
 .div{
   color:$text-foreground;
  }
```

And in the app.component.html.. depending on the condition, i can toggle the dark or light class.

```
<div [ngClass]="selectedClass">
....... // The main app content lies here 
....... // selectedClass can be either light or dark
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It throws because you've declared the variable in a scope. It's not available outside it. You cannot create themes like this because Sass is a language that gets compiled into CSS, which means that variables are stripped away. You'll need to have CSS for both themes if this is the way you want to implement them (although I suggest using actual CSS custom properties instead of this).

You can do it by taking leverage of [`:host-context`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context) in styles for your components.

```
:host-context(.dark) { color: black }
:host-context(.light) { color: white }
```

From the docs:

> Sometimes it's useful to apply styles based on some condition outside of a component's view. For example, a CSS theme class could be applied to the document `<body>` element, and you want to change how your component looks based on that.
>
> Use the `:host-context()` pseudo-class selector, which works just like the function form of `:host()`. The `:host-context()` selector looks for a CSS class in any ancestor of the component host element, up to the document root. The `:host-context()` selector is useful when combined with another selector.

In other words, you can add the current theme as a class to a element high in the hierarchy, such as `body` or your app's root element.

Comment: If I use :host-context(.dark) and :host-context(.light) and set the colors as black or white in them, there is no use for the variables right.. If my app has multiple components, then this approach would be a huge task.. Is there any other alternative where i can define the colors for black and white up ahead and based on the user action, I can toggle the themes??

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet

**Global SCSS**

```
// Light colors
$light-background:#ffffff;
$light-text-foreground: #000000;
$light-text-foreground-onhover: #ffffff;
$light-text-background-onhover: #000000;

// Dark colors:
$dark-background:#000000;
$dark-text-foreground: #000000;
$dark-text-foreground-onhover: #ffffff;
$dark-text-background-onhover: #000000;
```

**Component SCSS**

```
@import '../shared/style/global'; // --> change the location according to yours

.paragraph{
  &.dark-theme{
    background: $dark-background;
  }
  &.light-theme{
    background: $light-background;
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="paragraph" [ngClass]="toggleTheme()">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
toggleTheme(){
  // Set your appropriate logic to select active theme
  // return {'dark-theme':true};
  //or  return {'light-theme':true};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost doing it correctly, but there are two points:

1. You need to define variables outside `.dark` and `.light`
2. You should import the global style into components where you want to use those variables.

Here is `global.scss` which contains variables:

```
// Light colors
$light-background:#ffffff;
$light-text-foreground: #000000;
$light-text-foreground-onhover: #ffffff;
$light-text-background-onhover: #000000;

// Dark colors:
$dark-background:#000000;
$dark-text-foreground: #000000;
$dark-text-foreground-onhover: #ffffff;
$dark-text-background-onhover: #000000;
```

And here is component `scss`:

```
// First you need to import the global.scss
@import '../shared/style/global'; // --> This line
div{
  color:$dark-background;
}
```

Comment: If i have to toggle the theme on runtime from dark to light.. how can I do it with your approach ?